# fileupload is undefined function in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

i wrote a following code in jquery for file upload check.
plugins: jquery-1.7.min.js, jquery.fileupload.js, jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In ajax

```
$('#img1').fileupload(function(){


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FileUploadServlet",
    data: $('#userimage').serialize(),
    dataType:"json",                                               

success : function(examdata) {                                              

    //alert(examdata);
    //$("#errorbox").html(examdata);
    if(examdata[0]==0)
        {

        $('#img1').focus();
        $("#usererror").html("uploaded photo doesn't have any human faces please upload another image");
        }
    else
        {
        //$('#password').focus();
        $("#usererror").html("photo uploaded");
        }

}
});
    });
```

The error on this line fileupload(function() is undefined function.

The error:undefined is not a function at jquery.fileupload.js:87

line 87 in fileupload.js file is

```
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {
```

am i doing anything wrong in my code?

please help to solve this problem...

Comment: Are you sure you have "fileupload" method in the js file?

Comment: The console shows that error in the fileupload.js plugin...

Comment: Please add the error in your question

Comment: Do you have `img1` id in your page? Looks like the id is different.